# How do I create a 2d int array with different lengths in scala?

Tags: scala

How do I do the scala equivalent of this java code

```
int[][] vals = new int[4][];
for (int i=0; i < vals.length; i++) {
  vals[i] = new int[1 + 2*i];
}
```

The Array.ofDim method takes two parameters

Comment: This is called a "ragged array." Do you actually want an array, or would a list suffice?

Comment: i need an actual array for speed and memory utilization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
Array.tabulate(4)(i => Array.ofDim[Int](1 + 2 * i))
```

It will be much slower, however. If this code is in a critical path, you should do a while loop to make it much like in Java.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be:

```
Array.tabulate(4)(i => new Array[Int](1 + 2 * i))
```

Comment: @Daniel Why almost? It produces exactly the same result as the code in your answer...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the "`new`" keyword, so it looked to me like it would create 1-sized arrays with `1 + 2 * i` as content. Sorry about that, yours is indeed the same.